# How to receive multiple complex objects using HTTP POST method in Web App

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-post

I want to call an web api method, this is how my web api method looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("PostMyService/updatedBy/{updatedByID}/myobjname")]
        public void PostTerminalService([FromBody]  List<SomeType> lstSomeObj, MyClass myobj, int updatedByID)
{
//Do Something
}
```

This is how my client looks like:

```
int loggedinuserid=1;
  List<Sometype> liTS = new List<SomeType>();
MyClass myobj=new MyClass();
    var url = "api/XYZ/PostMyService/updatedBy/" + loggedinuserid + "/myobjname/" + myobj;
    HttpResponseMessage response = client1.PostAsJsonAsync(url, liTS).Result;
```

But the error/exception I am getting is:
**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
Most likely causes:
•The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
•The URL contains a typographical error.
•A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.**

Any idea how to resolve this? I am kind of hitting a wall on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have "api/XYZ/" prefixed in your client code, but I don't see it on your server code. I predict that you have it in your server configuration but if not you will see issues.
2. You can only have one object with the [FromBody] tag in WebAPI, it's not clear how your trying to pass the `MyClass` object.
3. Only simple objects, ints and strings, can be passed in the uri string so the `MyClass` object will not be transferred correctly.

I would recommend removing the `MyClass` object or creating a larger object that encapsulates your `List<SomeType> and`MyClass` and pass that in the body of the request with the [FromBody] decoration.

[Here's more information on the topic](http://blog.travisgosselin.com/web-api-signatures-with-multiple-complex-parameters/)